# Show that $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}>4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In my reading, I ran into the following inequality:
$$
\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}>4
$$
where $x,y>0$ and, without loss of generality, $x>y$.
I'm not sure how the authors were able to prove this. I can write
$$
\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}=\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{xy}>\frac{2xy}{xy}=2
$$
When I plot the function $z=f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}$ in GeoGebra, I can see that it never passes below $z=4$ for $x,y>0$.

How can I prove the first inequality?

Comment: Multiple both sides by $xy$ and do a little thinking.

Comment: Ahh, I got it now. As an aside, is it standard on SE for me to answer the question now, wait for someone else to answer it, or close the question entirely?

Comment: I suspect it will be closed shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow you steps, and move further ahead:

$$
\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}=\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{xy}=\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2+4xy}{xy}....
$$

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following deduction:

$\begin{align*} (x-y)^2 &> 0 \\
\Longrightarrow x^2 -2xy + y^2 &> 0 \\
\Longrightarrow x^2 + 2xy + y^2 &> 4xy \\
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 5):

$\dfrac{(x+y)^2}{xy} > 4 \iff (x+y)^2> 4xy \iff x^2+2xy+y^2> 4xy \iff x^2-2xy+y^2> 0$. This is true for all positive $x>y$ because $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$ which is always positive.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to prove this.
$$\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy}>4$$
is the AM-GM inequality
$$
{x+y\over2}>\sqrt{xy}
$$
It's also the rearrangement inequality
$$
x x+y y>x y+ yx
$$
It follows from Jensen's inequality for $f(x)=x^2$
$$
(x/2+y/2)^2<(x^2+y^2)/2
$$
so multiplying by 4 we get
$$
2xy<x^2+y^2.
$$
You can set $x=r\sin\theta$ and $y=r\cos\theta$ and then
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2>2xy=r^2\sin2\theta.
$$